# Which Visual Studio 2013 project template should I select for the most basic web site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, jquery-plugins, visual-studio-2013

I am about to create a web site that will be quite basic in that it will be just one page with a google map on it, and a few input checkboxes. It will have jQuery behind it, but I have no need for Bootstrap or MVC or Authentication or a database for this project. I want to use VS 2013 for the editor niceties and the ASP.NET framework it will provide (web.config, etc.), but for the most part it will be a bare bones HTML5/CSS/jQuery site.

So what is the most appropriate project template (C#) for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just select an **"Empty"** template. Later you can build your own site like you want.

See: [Creating ASP.NET Web Projects in Visual Studio 2013](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/creating-web-projects-in-visual-studio#overview)

[Empty Template](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/creating-web-projects-in-visual-studio#empty)

> The Empty template provides the bare minimum folders and files for an
>   ASP.NET web site, such as a project file (.csproj or .vbproj) and a
>   Web.config file. You can add support for Web Forms, MVC, and/or Web
>   API by using the check boxes under the Add folders and core references
>   for: label.

Comment: This answered my question, but on seeing just how minimal an "Empty" project is (they weren't kiddin'!), I think I'll start with a more full-featured project and just jettison the stuff I don't want (database, authentication, etc.). IOW, I still want to have a Site.CSS file, Content folder, &c.